# Where can I find a downloadable database of movies, music and/or actors

Tags: nlp

I'm writing a bit of software that can understand bits and pieces of sentences, but in order to properly categorise things, I need a database of movies, musicians, music, etc. Does anyone know where I could begin looking to find such a thing?

Answer (score 0):

I have got the sample list of movies database in .csv format from [this link](http://www.tanmaybakshi.com/training.csv).This list consists of movie series names ,year and ratings.